# Do I really need to put my website inside an app with Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a new big project using Django. Thing is, I want most of the content on the main page 127.0.0.1:8000 and not 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp. I know I can build everything also outside of an app, but is it a good practice ? Or what to do here ? Thanks.

Comment: These things are not related. Everything is an app in Django, but that doesn't mean you have to put it on a subpath.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thing is I noticed something akward when deploying a previous project on pythonanywhere. My project was like pythonanywhere.com/myapp but it was also displaying in pythonanywhere.com just like that (path was /myapp). Why did that happen ?

Comment: Presumably that's how you defined the urls.

Comment: like @DanielRoseman said, you can do this in urls by using - for example - `url('^/', views.mainview)`